# Delete projects from SonarQube which lasts for more than one week

Tags: sonarqube

I want to delete all the projects which was not used more than a week ago in SonarQube. Is there any setting available to automate this task or anything that can be done manually?

As of now I am deleting projects from project management where i can select multiple projects.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to expand on what you mean by "used". If you're looking for projects which haven't been analyzed in more than a week, that's fairly easy to find. If you're looking for projects that haven't been accessed in more than a week, you'll need to parse access logs.

Comment: am sorry for that, what i meant is the project which is not accessed more than a week.